# Resharper if statement auto completion

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I don't get what Resharper is try do here with the auto completion

what is the meaning of this?

```
if(VScroll)
{

}
```

if so can i change it something else? like this

```
if(bool)
{

}
```

Comment: It is difficult to answer from the context, but it might be that Resharper changed `if(VScroll == true)` to `if(VScroll)` which would be completely valid. `VScroll == true` evaluates to the same boolean value as `VScroll` by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to give a solid answer, but it could just be assuming based on the function you are implementing it into that you want to check VScroll's value, but you will be fine ignoring anything suggested by Resharper, however I like to follow most of the suggestions it gives me :)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.vscroll%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: it kinda annoying really can i change it to the default visual studio completion double tab?